# how do I correctly negate multiple zsh globbing expressions?

Tags: zsh

I have a directory with files. All the files have extensions. The extensions fall into one of 3 types: `txt`, `foo` and `bar`.

I want to print all files that do not end in `foo` neither `bar`.

I already know how to list all files that does not end in `foo`:

```
set extended_glob
print ^*.foo
```

but how to combine that negation to also exclude `*.bar`?

something like

```
print ^(*.foo & *.bar)
```

does not work. Man page did not help with this.

how to achieve the desired behaviour?

Comment: Go back to BASH. I tried using ZSH for about 9 months. I ended up just porting everything that I liked about oh-my-zsh and zsh back to BASH.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

found the answer:

```
print ^*.(foo|bar)
```

Comment: You could save a bit of typing by only grouping the parts that differ: `print ^*.(foo|bar)`. Also, the *zsh* manual does not explicitly say so, but it is possible chain more than two options: `print ^*.(foo|bar|baz)`.